# which HTML tags "support" background-color

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I get/produce a list of all HTML elements (tagNames) for which background-color is meaningful (that is has an effect) ?

For example DIV should be in the list but LINK should not.

(I need this to optimize a chrome extension that goes over the entire DOM and calculate new background color values)

Comment: I never noticed that `<link>` doesn't show a background color, even if you set the `display`. Weird.

Comment: `<link>` is an element that should only be in the non-visible `<head>` element, and never in the `<body>`. This question betrays an ignorance of how CSS and HTML (or really, *any* structured document data, like SGML, even JSON) work together.

Comment: @Dai If you can cite in the spec why this happens, we'd all be enlightened. Also, asking any question betrays ignorance; that's what a question is.

Comment: only this tags don't have `background-color`: `<base>`, `<link>`, `<meta>`, `<noscript>`, `<script>`, `<style>`, `<template>`, `<title>`.

Comment: Di, "This question betrays an ignorance of how CSS and HTML " .. well thx, I know that LINK is not visible etc, I need a full list of all tags for which background-image is not meaningful, LINK is just one of them

Comment: @Dai just because a tag should be in the head, doesn't mean a browser won't render it anyway if it isn't.

Comment: so ? what's your point ? background-color will never show on link elements regardless of where they are

Comment: @kofifus CSS does not have any intrinsic knowledge or rule-set regarding HTML - it's why you can literally invent your own HTML tags/elements (like `<foobar>`) and create a CSS rule `foobar { color: red; }` and it will just work. And if an element (like `<link>`) doesn't seem to have certain rules apply to them, it's actually because the default user-agent stylesheet (which is the what defines the default appearance for  known elements) applies properties that cause other properties to appear non-functioning. This is contrary to your opinion that the `link> itself cannot support BG color.

Comment: @kofifus Here is the default stylesheet for WebKit ( https://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css ) - you can see near the top they define `head, link, meta, script, style, title` with `display: none`, for example, which is why `background-color` doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### UPDATE

After much discussion of what the specific behaviour actually is, I think it has been demonstrated that any element (inlcuding made-up ones) will can have the background set, just as it says in the spec.

So, perhaps your chrome extension should check to see if elements have `display: none`, `height: 0`, or `width: 0` and exclude them from your list by these criteria. That is, exclude elements that are being hidden from displaying in the viewport.

---

According to [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html), all elements can have a `background` and `background-color`. However, some elements are not allowed inside a `<body>` and so should not ever be displayed on a web page. I don't know which of these (or why!) simply do not render a background or color, but these can be skipped by your extension.

```
<base>
<link>
<meta>
<noscript>
<script>
<style>
<template>
<title>
```

There may be more elements that are not generally displayed, but these are from the Metadata section of the [HTML5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#metadata-content-0).

Comment: yes many elements 'can have' a background-color property, but it will not be 'meaningful' for example canvas

Comment: in FF a script tag will happily display a background color. a link tag will also if you give it a height

Comment: Maybe it just boils down to initial css states of each of these items; by my reading of the spec, all of these should be able to have background colors, and if you set a `display` and a `height` some of these will show like a normal display element. More experimentation is required.

Comment: @kofifus adding a background on a canvas is really meaningful. If you've got an color/image/gradient that should always be drawn behind your canvas drawings, you'll win in perfs by setting it through css and not draw it at each frame.

Answer (score 1):

The specification said **all elements**. But you have to think if it make sense or not :)

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background-properties

```
Value:      <color> | transparent | inherit
Initial:    transparent
Applies to:     all elements
Inherited:      no
Percentages:    N/A
Media:      visual
Computed value:     as specified
```